# AWS: Cognito integration with a beta HTTP API in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Amazon Web Services introduced a beta release of [HTTP API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/) as a new product on API Gateway early last month. Its authentication is managed using JSON Web Tokens and configured [with a form](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/#attachment_8190) asking for

1. "Name of the Authorizer"
2. "Identity Source... a selection expression that defines the source of the token"
3. "Issuer URL"

I'm not very familiar with authentication protocols at all or what these form fields are asking, and currently the documentation from AWS on how to configure this to work with Cognito is [sparse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html). I'm not totally comfortable configuring this without guidance due to my lack of experience. Another Stack Overflow user seemed to have [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584335/api-gateway-new-beta-http-api) but didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

AWS is using **JWT Bearer Grant** for this purpose.
Draft Specification [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-12).

It allows HTTP API Gateway to accept JWT Tokens in the incoming **Authorization** HTTP header containing a **self-contained JWT access token** issued by third-party authorization servers (like Cognito, Azure AD, etc).

API Gateway validates the incoming JWT Token by matching the 'iss' value with the issuer URL to see if it can trust this token.

Try with these values.

- Name of the authorizer: **Registered client name in your Cognito User Pool** .
- Identity Source: Leave it as default, **$request.header.Authorization** .
- Issuer URL: Check the metadata URL of your Cognito User Pool (construct the URL in this format :: https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/.well-known/openid-configuration :: look for a claim named **"issuer"**. Copy its Value and paste it here.
- Audience: **Client ID of your Registered client in Cognito**

Good Luck!

cheers,
ram

Comment: I can build the URL in the format you provided. But still, where can I find the ` metadata URL of my Cognito User Pool`? I have digged through my AWS Cognito console page and can not find it. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C If you paste the constructed URL into a browser, I assume the returned response is what OP meant as the metadata. In general, Issuer URL is `https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolID]`.

Answer (score 25):

Used @ram answer to get through, and was able to implement this

**1.Name of the authorizer**:

AWS Cognito > User pools > App Integration > App client settings > App client :

Example :  `xxxxxx_app_clientWeb`

**2.Identity Source** : `$request.header.Authorization`

**3.Issuer URL**

- construct the URL to get Cognito user pool metadata ( https://cognito-idp..amazonaws.com//.well-known/openid-configuration)
  Example :

`https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_FcgSrx2141/.well-known/openid-configuration`

- open the URL and you will see a json
- take the "issuer" value

Example :

```
"issuer":"https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_FcgSrx2141"
```

Take: `https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_FcgSrx2141`

**4. Audience:** AWS Cognito > User pools > App Integration > App client settings > App clientID
Example :

```
ID 9sptej55gii5dfp08ulplc343
```

Take: `9sptej55gii5dfp08ulplc343`

Answer (score 1):

This video explains the whole process and configuration like no other.

~~ https://www.coursera.org/lecture/building-modern-java-applications-on-aws/use-amazon-cognito-to-sign-in-and-call-api-gateway-s226R ~~

[Update 2024-03-04. Video not available. Alternative link to similar resources]

https://www.google.com/search?q=+aws+cognito+sign+in+api+gateway

I am thankful that the video is public.

Note: (As far as I know) The course is from AWS but offered to the public through different MOOC websites (not just this one).

---

Once you have read & played enough, you will start seeing the gems within the details.

The word "Token" for example, is mentioned in many docs, but it can be Access Token / Id Token / Refresh Token / ... If you don't realize about this you can be wasting your time.

For example the "Implicit grant" doesn't provide a Refresh-Token, so you cannot renew your Access-Token and trying to do it is useless.

Comment: This video is not available anymore. Not sure this answer is of any help at this point.