# AWS Cognito: where is the metadata URL of Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito as an authorizer for my REST API in AWS API Gateway.

It asks me to fill in the `Issuer URL`:

[image]

Digging through the AWS Cognito User Pool page, there is no such thing.

I found a related answer here: [AWS: Cognito integration with a beta HTTP API in API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596722/aws-cognito-integration-with-a-beta-http-api-in-api-gateway)
and I quote:

```
Issuer URL: Check the metadata URL of your Cognito User Pool 
(construct the URL in this format :: https://cognito-idp.
[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/.well-known/openid-configuration 
:: look for a claim named "issuer". Copy its Value and paste it here.
```

I can of course build the url as said above.

But still, where is the `metadata URL of my Cognito User Pool`????

Am I missing something really basic and being absolutely silly by asking this question?

Where is it??

This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issuer URL of a Cognito User Pool has the following format:

```
https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]
```

As you stated correctly, you can get it from Cognito's well-known metadata endpoint, which is available at

```
https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

This file is JSON-formatted and contains an `issuer` field, which contains the URL mentioned above. The whole file looks like this:

```
{
   "authorization_endpoint":"https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/authorize",
   "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[
      "RS256"
   ],
   "issuer":"https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]",
   "jwks_uri":"https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/.well-known/jwks.json",
   "response_types_supported":[
      "code",
      "token"
   ],
   "scopes_supported":[
      "openid",
      "email",
      "phone",
      "profile"
   ],
   "subject_types_supported":[
      "public"
   ],
   "token_endpoint":"https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/token",
   "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[
      "client_secret_basic",
      "client_secret_post"
   ],
   "userinfo_endpoint":"https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/[userPoolId]/userInfo"
}
```

Comment: I wish they could write clearly that the Issuer URL has such and such format. or maybe I am just missing it in the doc